# Finding rows younger/older than a specific row without subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, where-clause

I have a table `cats` with columns `id` and `birthday`. `id` is not guaranteed to represent the chronological order of the underlying data.

In this schema setup, if we want to find cats younger/older than a given cat, we can construct the query using subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM cats WHERE created_at < (SELECT created_at FROM cats WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1)
```

But I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways to make this query. This is with Postgres specifically, but I'd be curious if the answer might differ with other database engines.

Thank you,

Comment: IMO it is the most efficient way (assuming that the both columns are indexed)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine, and should be an efficient approach at the problem. The `limit` clause in the subquery is superflous, provided that `id` is a unique column.

An alternative is a self-join:

```
select c.*
from cats c
inner join cats c1 on c.created_at < c1.created_at
where c1.id = ?
```

Or you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select c.*,
        min(created_at) filter(where id = ?) over() created_at1
    from cats c
) c
where created_at < created_at1
```

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cats c
WHERE c.created_at < (SELECT c2.created_at FROM cats c2 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1);
```

Should be quite efficient with an index on `cats(id, created_at)`.  Note that the `LIMIT` should not be necessary.

This will scan the `cats` table and do a quick lookup for the subquery using the index.  It is hard to think of a faster way of running the query.